# Order date in Ascending order in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried ordering date in order with AM and PM. but facing some issues in that. I have added my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/indhu_velayutham/25x9bpn1/31/) with this. can someone help me in this.

```
function sortAscending(a, b) {
var date1 = $(a).find("time").text();
date1 = date1.split('/');
date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0]);

var date2 = $(b).find("time").text();
date2 = date2.split('/');
date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1] - 1, date2[0]);


return date1 < date2;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrapper .cards').sort(sortAscending).appendTo('#wrapper');
});
```

this piece of code is for date not for time. how to sort the time with AM or PM

Comment: What issue you are facing? Please elaborate it.

Comment: I am trying to sort it in ascending order. 
without time I am able to sort the date. but with time and AM or PM i couldnt do it

Comment: Use moment, rolling your own date functions is counter intuitive when there is such a good package out there. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Why don't you sort the date first, then transform time to 'am','pm'.

Comment: Agree with @AdrianBrand if you still want to do it on your own, refer https://forums.asp.net/t/1989130.aspx?how+to+sort+datetime+by+jquery this has complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use moment, no point trying to roll your own date functions. Dates in JavaScript are hard and moment solves nearly any date requirements you will come across.

```js
function sortAscending(a, b) {
  return moment(a).isBefore(b);
}

console.log(sortAscending(new Date(), new Date()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: can you help me fixing my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/indhu_velayutham/dLh8kjmz/4/

Comment: The sort function needs to return -1, 0 or 1 not just greater than and it gets passes in a DOM object that was a div. You need to find the span with the date, parse with moment and then use that to return -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: the date is getting sorted, but not the time too

Comment: Then change the parse filter from 'DD/MM/YYYY' to the filter you need to include time 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a'

Comment: still AM PM is not sorting fine. can i use

         date1 = Date.parse(date1.replace("pm"," PM").replace("am"," AM"));

         date2 = Date.parse(date2.replace("pm"," PM").replace("am"," AM"));

Comment: Did you look at the example in the fiddle? a is the selector for meridian which is the AM/PM part

Comment: yes I see that. But i tried with values. it was not checking with AM | PM, so asked

Answer (score 0):

Sort functions in JS must return 1, -1 or 0, you are returning a boolean.

You should be changing the last line:

```
return a - b; //This will do the work
```

Eventually you can also implement like:

```
return (date1 < date2) ? -1 : (date1 > date2) ? 1 : 0;
```

This means if date1 comes previously place it before, if it comes after date2 place it later, otherwise don't move them.

Just a piece of advice I got stuck in my head. Provided a < b e.g. a = 3 and b = 10.

return a - b <-- b is taller than a figuratively is increasing, like a volume icon. This will place in ascending order.

return b - a <-- b is taller than a figuratively is decreasing, like a slope. Will place the item in descending order.

This helped me keep in mind what to return.

---

UPDATE: Working the elements while being in a jQuery collection has proven difficult, so with a bit of an overhead this is working:

```
function sortAscending(a, b) {   <--This works outside of the realm of a jQuery object
var time = a.getElementsByTagName('time')[0]
date1 = time.textContent.split(' ')[0];
date1 = date1.split('/')
date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0]);

var time2 = b.getElementsByTagName('time')[0]
date2 = time2.textContent.split(' ')[0];
date2 = date2.split('/');
date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1] - 1, date2[0]);


return date1 - date2;
}

$(document).ready(function() { <--This deconstruct, sort, and reconstruct a jQuery collection
    $( $('#wrapper .cards').toArray().sort(sortAscending) ).appendTo($('#wrapper'))
});
```